# CPAN error (Segmentation fault 11)

Tags: segmentation-fault, cpan, bioperl

I wanted to get some advice on an error I am getting on my mac whenever I try to launch CPAN. I'm trying to install BioPerl on my machine, but whenever I try to launch cpan or execute the following:

`perl -MCPAN -e shell`

I get an error `Segmentation fault: 11`. I can overcome this when I preface the command with `sudo`. This is the same thing when I try to install BioPerl on my mac (OS X El Capitan) as per the following steps.

`git clone https://github.com/bioperl/bioperl-live.git`
`cd bioperl-live`
`perl Build.PL)`

Does anyone have any advice as to what's going on or what I should do or worry about? I am in no way a developer and any explanation to a novice like me would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but after installing the following three modules, cpan started working again.

```
$ cpan Term::ReadLine::Perl
$ cpan Term::ReadKey
$ cpan YAML
```